# Handle keyboard input on shell

Tags: c, shell, input

I am developing a custom shell like bash (in C).
I am working right now on the events triggered by the arrows and the tab key. However, those special keys should be handled correctly.

What I want is to capture those keys and not let the CLI draw them on screen. What happens is that when the up arrow is pressed, for example, it draws the following symbol: '^[[A'

How can I stop it from happening? And what is the best way to read and map those keys?

Comment: I recommend using a library such as [GNU Readline](http://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html). If nothing else, you can see how they handle keyboard input.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I will take a look at this library.

Comment: UP key actually sends 3 keystrokes; <esc (ascii=27)>,[,A. You need to make an FSM, to handle up/down keys. I remember I had once attempted to do so. You need to store previous commands in an array of strings.

Comment: @anishsane What is a FSM? Do you have any reference from where I could start?

Comment: Oh, FSM is finite state machine. Check wikipedia for examples. I think, you can write a C code yourself, after understanding what FSM is.

Answer (score 1):

It's kind of old, but some shells use terminal capabilities (termcaps) to block output and move the cursor.

You can also use the lib ncurses that is a cool wrapper for termcaps.